# window.onbeforeunload handling ok and cancel options

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.onunload

I have a `window.onbeforeunload` function which generates the default message:

> "Are you sure you want to navigate away from  this page...." .

If we click on <kbd>OK</kbd> we are redirected to a new link and if we press <kbd>cancel</kbd> we are redirected back to the same page.

I want to save some data from the page when we press <kbd>OK</kbd>  and move away from the page. How can we know if <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>cancel</kbd> has been pressed, then make an event call and continue with the "ok"/"cancel" option.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach might be to hook into the `onunload` event as well, and if that handler is called, you know that the user chose `OK`.

In `onbeforeunload`, set a timeout callback that is called some time afterwards (e.g. 1 second), and if it is called, the user might have selected `Cancel`.

Not sure how safe this is regarding race conditions though.

Comment: That does work, however, 1 second is too short making it an absolute horrible way of knowing whether the user decided to cancel. I had to use a timeout of 5 to 10 seconds to make sure I get it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
function leavePage() {
    //do your thing like saving the data in the session
    return "Some data entered may be lost."; //a text needs to be returned
}

window.onbeforeunload = leavePage;
```

Comment: I want to save data only when I press "ok" and not when i press "cancel". In your solution the data will be saved in both the cases.

Answer (score -2):

Are you using JavaScript 'confirm' dialog?

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page....")) {
    // OK was pressed
} else {
    // Cancel was pressed
}
```

Comment: The dialog is probably generated by the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: You cannot use the `confirm()` function in the `onunloadbefore()`. It won't work. The browser creates a confirmation dialog when you return a string.