# Unbind window.onbeforeunload() cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm binding a function to an event with

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 somefunction()
}
```

which is working on unload as planned, but if they cancel the onbeforeunload the function is still attached, is it possible to check if the user cancels onbeforeunload

Comment: What do you mean by `cancel the onbeforeunload`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onbeforeunload handling ok and cancel options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579326/window-onbeforeunload-handling-ok-and-cancel-options)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually, I found it was quite easy: I just set

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

for each click before it was run, allowing the event handler to be run afterwards.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to suppress the Leave/Stay prompt conditionally, but haven't figured this out yet. If the form is dirty, then I'd like to prompt the user otherwise skip that. Any suggestions?

Comment: return undefined should work to supress the prompt. more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes

Answer (score 3):

or you can just return null

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return null;
};
```

I am using following snippet for that: [window.onbeforeunload gist](https://gist.github.com/woss/3c2296d9e67e9b91292d#file-window-prevent-reload)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get the Leave/Stay prompt popping up.

Comment: @PongGod: return undefined should work. more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes

Answer (score 0):

also I just add more suggestion with following answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20057278/3710376

It can run a function and ignore any popup confirmation.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 somefunction()
 window.onbeforeunload = false;
}
```